# APEX report displays uneditable checkbox

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a classic report, one column of which is generated with APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX. The checkboxes are displayed and they are displayed with the value from the database - either checked or unchecked. The issue is that sometimes I need to update the checkbox value and the checkboxes created appear uneditable. WHich property should I change to enable the checkbox to be checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to `apex_item.checkbox` is `p_attributes`.  For the checkbox to be appearing as disabled this must already be being passed a value like `disabled="disabled"`.  The solution is to remove that from the value passed in (i.e. probably pass in null).

Comment: no, actually it only has this: `<input type="checkbox" name="f01" value="1" checked>`

Comment: In that case perhaps there is some Javascript or a dynamic action on the page that is disabling them?